# R: using corrplot to visualize two variables (e.g., correlation and p-value) using the size and colour of the circles

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I am trying to recreate someone's image using corrplot. This is the original image I am trying to re-create:

[image]

I use the following R-code:

```
corrplot(as.matrix(rgs), 
         method="circle", 
         type="upper", 
         col=brewer.pal(n=8, name="PuOr"), 
         tl.col="black", 
         tl.srt=45, 
         p.mat = as.matrix(pvalues), 
         sig.level = 0.05, 
         insig = "blank")
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

The problem I have is that the colour as well as the size of the circles in my plot are based on the correlations, but in the original image above the colour of the circles is based on the correlation while the size of the circles is based on the p-values. I have the p-values in a different data frame called pvalues (I actually use that in the code above to determine which circles should be shown and which shouldn't in the bottom 3 lines). My question is: how can I make the colour and size be dependent on two different variables like they did in the original image? Is that even possible using corrplot?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could make your example reproducible. What is rgs, where did you get the p-values from.

Comment: @JBGruber It looks like the chart came from [this scientific article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867419312760#mmc9), where there are also some downloadable data sets. It would be much easier if the OP gave us some sample data.

Comment: Please, give data, see [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want does not seem to be possible with `corrplot`, unless you hack it a bit. I simply added a new parameter `size_vector` which is used when drawing the circles. See https://github.com/johannes-titz/corrplot/commit/9362f6a7c2fda794b5ef8895b77f0b2ff979092a for the changed lines.

```
# install the hacked version
devtools::install_github("johannes-titz/corrplot@size_parameter")
library(corrplot)
data(mtcars)
M <- cor(mtcars)
# get p values
p_vals_mat <- cor.mtest(mtcars)$p
corrplot(M, size_vector = 1-as.numeric(p_vals_mat))
```

[image]

Note that I used 1-p for the size (small p-values produce large circles). You can use any value between 0 and 1 for the size.

Further note that in the original figure, the relationship between the p-value and the circle size is non-linear. So you might want to use some transformation that comes close to this relationship.

In any case I would actually advise to not use such figures. p-values are problematic on their own, but plotting them with some kind of transformation does not make much sense to me. The size of the correlation is likely the most important information and the plot does not reflect this. This has some potential for confusions.

PS: I did not bother to add a legend, but this should not be too difficult to do with `legend`.

**A small update:**
The transformation of the p-values might be something like this:

```
transform_p <- function(x) {
  y <- 0.91 - (0.82) * (1 - exp(-3.82 * x))
  y
}
```

Which will slightly change the size of the circles:

```
corrplot(M, size_vector = as.numeric(transform_p((p_vals_mat))))
```

[image]

Again, I do not recommend it, but it should be a bit closer to the original figure.

If you just want the upper triangular, only pass the p-values of the upper triangular:

```
upper_tri <- p_vals_mat[upper.tri(p_vals_mat, diag = T)]
corrplot(M, size_vector = transform_p(upper_tri), type = "upper")
```

[image]

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. However, it's probably better to have a wrapper function that temporarily overwrites the lines in the function rather than reinstalling the package. Check out `unlockBinding` to allow access to the function and use `body(corrplot)` to make the changes. You can then change it back before exiting the wrapper.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much! I agree with your advise, I will also produce a Figure that does not visualize the p-values like that, but I need this one as well just for comparison. I only have one problem left in your solution, namely, if I use the option type="upper", I get the following error message: "Error in symbols(Pos, add = TRUE, inches = FALSE, circles = asp_rescale_factor *  : 
  x/y/parameter length mismatch". Any idea why this is?

Comment: @Allan: Thank you! I was wondering if this is possible but in the end it was easier for me to upload a novel version to github. Actually, the package should work as before. I added a condition to check if the new parameter is null. If it is, the function uses the correlation for the radius of the circle (as usual). Otherwise, it uses the manually defined size. Sorry, I do not have time to try your suggestion, but it sounds very good!

Comment: @Abdel: this is expected since the `upper` option requires fewer elements of vector_size. Just pass the upper triangular of the p value matrix: `corrplot(M, size_vector = p_vals_mat[upper.tri(p_vals_mat, diag = T)], type = "upper")`

Comment: Hello, I am trying to use this solution but I keep running into installation errors Error: Failed to install 'corrplot' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/var/folders/1m/1pbv4y0158b1108zl0vwcnxm0000gn/T//RtmpmkKVPd/file148b67086f13a/corrplot_0.85.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: Just tested it, it still works for me. Is your system up to date?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this person used `ggcor`, which is a package under development. If you do:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("houyunhuang/ggcor")

library(ggplot2)
library(ggcor)

quickcor(fortify_cor(mtcars,cor.test = T), type = "upper") + 
  geom_circle2(aes(fill = r,r0 = p.value))
```

[image]

You can have the size varying with the p value

```
fortify_cor(mtcars,cor.test = T)
```

creates a table of correlation, with the p values

```
# A tibble: 121 x 8
   .row.names .col.names      r  p.value upper.ci lower.ci .row.id .col.id
 * <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <int>   <int>
 1 mpg        mpg         1     0.          1       1           11       1
 2 cyl        mpg        -0.852 6.11e-10   -0.716  -0.926       10       1
 3 disp       mpg        -0.848 9.38e-10   -0.708  -0.923        9       1
 4 hp         mpg        -0.776 1.79e- 7   -0.586  -0.885        8       1
 5 drat       mpg         0.681 1.78e- 5    0.832   0.436        7       1
 6 wt         mpg        -0.868 1.29e-10   -0.744  -0.934        6       1
 7 qsec       mpg         0.419 1.71e- 2    0.670   0.0820       5       1
 8 vs         mpg         0.664 3.42e- 5    0.822   0.410        4       1
 9 am         mpg         0.600 2.85e- 4    0.784   0.318        3       1
10 gear       mpg         0.480 5.40e- 3    0.710   0.158        2       1
```

Comment: I get an error trying to install this package saying HTTP error, not found. Could you help? Has the file moved from that repository?

Comment: I have no idea. Try to contact the packge maintainer: https://rdrr.io/github/houyunhuang/ggcor/