# Visualise "corrplot" in R with more than one variable/parameter

Tags: r, correlation, cross-correlation, r-corrplot

I am using the `corrplot` function which is part of the `corrplot` package in `R` to visualise correlations between channels of data that I have. My question is whether I could possibly assign two "factors" or parameters to the circle... So, for example, could I have the size of the circle representing the correlation and the colour of the circle represents something else for example lags? My data is actually cross-correlation data where I have identified the maximum correlation/lag and want to be able to visualise both in a figure, that's why I want to do this.

Essentially what I am trying to achieve is the same as in this question: [R: using corrplot to visualize two variables (e.g., correlation and p-value) using the size and colour of the circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60410366/r-using-corrplot-to-visualize-two-variables-e-g-correlation-and-p-value-usi), however, neither of the solutions are working for me and I get an error when installing the packages from Github.

I have a vectors of lags and correlations:

```
CCO_lag = (0,   NaN ,   -2 ,  NaN  ,  -5  ,  -4  ,  -6  ,  -3  ,   0 ,  NaN ,    1  ,   3  , NaN   ,  0   , -3  , NaN) 
CCO_r = c(-0.4757 ,      NaN   , 0.5679    ,   NaN   , 0.5582  ,  0.5899 ,   0.5857 ,   0.6256 ,  -0.4646   ,    NaN ,  -0.6286 , -0.4699    ,   NaN ,  -0.7710  ,  0.5869  ,     NaN `)
```

And let's say I want to visualise this in a `1x16` square using `corrplot` I want the size of the circles to depend on the correlation value in `CCO_r` while the colour of the circles to depend on the lag value in `CCO_lag`.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a small reproducible example. And be specific about your package, there is a `ggcorrplot` package, a `corrplot` package, the `arm` package has a `corrplot` function... which are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to make it clearer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem much like a correlation plot to me, but we can do this:

```
CCO_lag = c(0,   NaN ,   -2 ,  NaN  ,  -5  ,  -4  ,  -6  ,  -3  ,   0 ,  NaN ,    1  ,   3  , NaN   ,  0   , -3  , NaN) 
CCO_r = c(-0.4757 ,      NaN   , 0.5679    ,   NaN   , 0.5582  ,  0.5899 ,   0.5857 ,   0.6256 ,  -0.4646   ,    NaN ,  -0.6286 , -0.4699    ,   NaN ,  -0.7710  ,  0.5869  ,     NaN )

d = data.frame(id = 1:length(CCO_lag), CCO_lag, CCO_r)

ggplot(d, aes(x = id, y = "A", size = CCO_r, color = CCO_lag)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = NULL) +
  labs(y = "", x = "")
```

[image]

If you've got matrices:

```
lag_mat = matrix(CCO_lag, 4)
r_mat = matrix(CCO_r, 4)
row = c(row(lag_mat))
col = c(col(lag_mat))

dd = data.frame(
  lag = c(lag_mat), r = c(r_mat), row, col
)

ggplot(dd, aes(x = row, y = col, size = r, color = lag)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Note that matrices have row 1 on top, with higher-numbered rows below, but plots have the lower y values on the bottom, with higher-numbered y values above. You may want to change that or it may be fine. You can add `scale_y_reverse()` to your plot to switch it.

Comment: Thanks... now my only issue is that my actual CCO_r and CCO_lag matrices are 16x16 rather than being 1x16... if I incorporate into the data frame as in the code it ends up being a dataframe of 256 observations which it plots in one line... how can I correctly read in those matrices into the dataframe? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I was confused that you only shared 16 values but you wanted a `1x16` square... not really square. I'll show how to turn this into a 4x4 square and then you can generalize up with your larger data.

Comment: In general, it's good to make sample data of the same type as your real data. If your real data is a matrix, make your sample data a (smaller) matrix.

Comment: Thanks! What does this part of the ggplot code do? "+[![enter image description here][2]][2]
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())" because I got this error: Error: unexpected '[' in:
"ggplot(dd, aes(x = row, y = col, size = r, color = lag)) +
  geom_point() +[" until I removed it and then I got the figure. Thanks for the tip! I'll definitely remember that for next time to include a smaller real data matrix!

Comment: Sorry - that's gone. That was Stack Overflow trying to add the image in the middle of my code instead of at the end (I think I had the cursor in the wrong place when I inserted the image - I was confused why it didn't show up the first time).

Comment: Ahh! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I have one more question... when I plot this I get the negative lags e.g. -6 to be small circles and then as it gets positive the circle gets bigger. I'm not sure how you would switch them around? i.e. big circles for negative lag and vice versa

Comment: `+ scale_size_area(trans = "reverse")` should do it.